# Is it possible to avoid C++ compiler error (C2757) where 2 different header files contain same symbol for namespace & class?

Tags: c++

I am facing a problem when implementing some new code to an existing library. This library already references a class with a name say '**foo**'. The same name is used as a namespace in the other header file which has to be included to implement the new functionality. Since both the header files are a part of legacy code libraries I cannot amend them. So here I am looking for any way so as to avoid the Compiler Error (C2757: *a symbol with this name already exists and therefore this name cannot be used as a namespace name*). I am not sure whether it is possible or not. Hence, Any help shall be appreciated. Thanks

For clarity here is the sample code illustration for the issue:

HeaderA.h

```
class foo
{}
```

HeaderB.h

```
namespace foo
{
class ABC{}
}
```

HeaderC.h

```
#include <HeaderA.h>
#include <HeaderB.h>
using namespace foo;

class Toimplement{
ABC a; //Throws Error C2757
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following workaround:

```
namespace bar {
    #include "HeaderA.h"
}
#include "HeaderB.h"

...
bar::foo fooObject;
foo::ABC abcObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

Include one of header file in new namespace.

```
namespace headerb {  
   #include <HeaderB.h>  
}  
...  
...  
headerb::ABC a1;
ABC b2;
```

Comment: That was quick! I created a new namespace and it is working correctly! I received some similar reference errors for other static values, but after adding namespace everything is fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the simplest approach is to not include `HeaderA.h` in `HeaderC.h`. The class foo isn't needed in Toimplement.

Comment: Pretty much this. Include what you need, don't include what you don't need.

Comment: I can't prevent that as I said it is an old code and they are using some class from HeaderA.h in their other parts of the current class.

Answer (score 0):

so let's assume you need the visibility of both files, and you want to link to the symbols included by HeaderA:

```
// header a
class FOO {};

// followed by a file with your declarations/disambiguators
typedef FOO wwlib_FOO;

// header b
namespace FOO {class ABC {};}

// followed by a file with your declarations/disambiguators
namespace vvlib_FOO = FOO;

// and finally usage
using namespace FOO; // note: using `using` is a good way to introduce complications like this one

void fn() {
    class FOO t;
    wwlib_FOO t2(t);
    vvlib_FOO::ABC abc;
...
```

the namespace trick won't work, apart from very very simple cases (unless it's entirely templates or inlines, which is very unusual). you'll just end up with duplicated code, classes that you can't pass around, and missing references at link-time.